# Apache2 throws 403 Forbidden error when accessing site resources

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I know that this has been posted about *a ton*, but I have spent the last day scouring through answers, trying everything and nothing is working. I've changed permissions, I've looked into the Apache2 logs, I've altered configuration files, and I'm still getting the 403 forbidden error. Here are the apache2. My html files are in `/var/www/html`.

I'm not completely sure, but I do recall troubles starting after trying to create user directories using:

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

Inside the Apache error logs, the only thing on there that could be leading to something is this:

```
(13)Permission denied: [client myip] AH00035: access to 
/folder/data/index.html denied (filesystem path 
'/var/www/html/folder/data/index.html') because search permissions are 
missing on a component of the path
```

In my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`, I added the following at the very end:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

In my `apache2.conf`I have the following:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride ALL
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride ALL
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Again, I'm *very* sorry that I needed to make this thread, but I don't want to continue to copy and paste solutions that could do more harm than good.

Comment: What are the permissions on `/var/www/html` ? Also check here for possible solution : https://superuser.com/questions/882594/permission-denied-because-search-permissions-are-missing-on-a-component-of-the-p

Comment: I chmod it to 755

Comment: You can check all the permissions with this command `find /var/www -type d -exec ls -lh {} \;` (for directories) and this `find /var/www -type f -exec ls -lh {} \;` (for files) to be sure.

Comment: I noticed you have `AllowOverride` set to `ALL` instead of `none` and this can cause a 403 error sometimes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171951/allowoverride-all-causes-error-403 Have you tried any of these other solutions outlined in this post?

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried everything you specified (checked permissions, allowed overrride set to none) and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty guys, so I know for most people this won't be the answer they're looking for. But to successfully fix this issue, I uninstalled apache2, and looked online for a lamp-stack install guide, and this new install fixed these errors!

Comment: Could you ... 1. Link to the guide. 2. Outline the essential parts of the guide that you found helpful. 3. Note how your current install is different from your previous one.